# Определение одного или менее символов в строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Доброго времени суток! Существует одна небольшая задачка по регулярным выражениям. Итак, есть строка "**/jQ6iU.jpg**", где нужно проверить точное количество определённых символов. Если в строке больше одного слеша **или** точки, то ошибка, а если слеша **или** точки нет вообще, то работаем дальше.

```
/jQ6iU.jpg - OK

/jQ6iU - OK

jQ6iU.jpg - OK

/jQ6iU.jpg/path - FALSE

/jQ6iU.jpg/path/foo.bar - FALSE
```

*Спасибо!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не люблю регулярки, поэтому сразу покажу альтернативный вариант. Если и не возьмете на вооружение, то по крайней мере будете в курсе:

```
$str = '/jQ6iU.jpg/path/foo.bar';
substr_count($str, '.'); // вернет кол-во точек
substr_count($str, '/'); // вернет кол-во слешей
```

Comment: Да, такой вариант у меня сейчас и работает. Просто хотелось всё красиво в одно условие сделать. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3):

[count_chars()](http://www.php.su/functions/?count_chars)

**UPD**

Я бы так расписал, в надежде на ясность кода и лёгкость модификации:

```
define( 'C_SLASH', ord('/') );
define( 'C_DOT',   ord('.') );

$words = array
(
    '/jQ6iU.jpg', '/jQ6iU', 'jQ6iU.jpg',
    '/jQ6iU.jpg/path', '/jQ6iU.jpg/path/foo.bar'
);

foreach( $words as $word )
{
    print "$word is ";
    print is_bad( $word ) ? "BAD\n" : "GOOD\n";
}

function is_bad( $word )
{
    $chars = count_chars( $word, 1);
    $bad = isset($chars[C_SLASH]) ? ($chars[C_SLASH] > 1) : 0;
    $bad += isset($chars[C_DOT]) ? ($chars[C_DOT] > 1 ) : 0;
    return $bad;
}
```

Comment: Хорошая реализация. Спасибо за ответ!